# Are people aware there is a chat room?

Tags: discussion

I am feeling slightly stupid at the moment I have been on StackExchange for many years now and I have only just stumbled upon the chatrooms section.

It appears we have a chat room that no-one knows about or uses: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/199/homebrew

Am I the only one who had no idea about this or given its state of unused does none else know these rooms exist?

And, what can we do about promoting this feature to users?